# Can any one let me know what is 'ALL' command in SQLserver 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

can any one let me know what is 'ALL' command and with proper example and clear explanation.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543%28v=sql.105%29.aspx have u googled it?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173270(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: @ Nitin :Yes, i googled it need detail example for complex query.

Comment: You should add the essential part of your complex query to your question.

Comment: I don't have any idea about this need know in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"The ALL keyword specifies that the search condition is TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for every value that the subquery returns. If the subquery returns no value, the condition is TRUE."*

Read more [Using the ALL Keyword](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls981.htm)

Hereis a simple example [SQL Server All](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLAllSome.aspx)

Comment: select * from employees where empid<> all (select empid from employees where empid> 35)  it returns all employee information which displays empid <35 and equal to 35 instead of 'all' we can use <=35 what is difference bitween <= and all.